# multiple Single-Channel outputs in GPUImage and OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, gpuimage

I am trying to use the GPUImage library for image processing (not for image output to screen).  By default, the library outputs one BGRA texture. I would like to instead output multiple single-channel/single-byte textures. Up to this point I have been bit-packing multiple calculations for each pixel in BGRA. I have reached the limitations of such a method because a) I now have greater than 4 return values for each pixel, and b) the overhead of de-interlacing BGRA-BGRA-BGRA-BGRA..... into BBBB..,GGGG..,RRRR..,AAAA.., is starting to really bog down my program.

I know there is some sample code for using multiple input textures with GPUImage, but I have not seen anything for multiple output textures. For single-byte output I believe I could use GL_ALPHA textures(?), so I am guessing it is a matter to binding multiple textures into variables in my filter kernel.

Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, your options for color formats in textures used as render targets are somewhat limited. I haven't tried, but I don't believe you can use GL_RED_EXT textures as FBO targets for one-component use, I think those are just for input textures. I do know that no currently shipping iOS device supports multiple render targets, so you may need to do your operations in several render passes. Why do you need to deinterlace your values in the end?

Comment: After a little digging, it turns out that you can use GL_RED_EXT textures as render targets, but that doesn't solve your core problem of needing multiple simultaneous targets. Multiple render passes with different shaders would be needed to pull out separate planes of data.

Comment: Would those be multiple shaders as part of the same "program"? I don't mind writing separate shaders, I am just concerned about the overhead. As long as the input memory doesn't need to be copied 5 times per frame to do that, I don't think it would be a problem. I will look to see what I can do with GL_RED_EXT. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, and the reason I am deinterlacing is because one channel is being handed off to a barcode reader library that only accepts one greyscale byte / pixel, and other channels are carrying data for a hue band-pass algorithm that pass individual heatmaps highlighting parts of the image with certain wavelengths of colors.

Comment: Multiple shader programs would probably be the way to go here. There isn't a tremendous amount of overhead in keeping multiple programs in memory (compilation and linking is the slow part, but that's ideally done once). Employing conditional statements in fragment shaders is horribly expensive on iOS devices and should be avoided if possible, so it's best to break out each case into its own shader program.

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you need is Multiple Rendering Targets (or MRT for short). You can inspect how many color attachments does you target hardware supports with GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT. Unfortunely I believe not all iOS devices support, if any.